# Power Automate - Flow not working in a solution

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

We have a solution deployed in a tenant which consists of flows and powerapps application. The flow in the solution has a trigger point of whenever an item is added or modified in SharePoint list. That flow is not getting triggered even when an item is added to the list or modified. But if we make a copy of the flow outside the solution it is working. Have you guys faced any issue like this?

Comment: Have you verified the flow is on? Have you verified the account in charge of the connection has access to the list?

Comment: Now it is working. Maybe because of the outage it may have been the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the trigger and re-adding it. If not please try that